# Process Builder Error: Maximum active interaction definitions reached

Tags: process-builder

When activating a Process, Process Builder throws up error: "Maximum active interaction definitions reached."

Search results on the internet didn't return any relevant results so I'm posting this up for anyone who may encounter it in future.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the maximum number of active workflows for your Salesforce Org has been reached. This is irrespective of active workflow limits on the object. The max number of active workflows per Salesforce Org (at time of writing is 500).